# How do the operators act on a ket/bra?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, notation

I am having trouble understanding how an operator actS when it is between a ket and a bra:

For example, let $\hat{a}$ be a ladder operator, as in a simple harmonic oscillator case, and let $\phi_n$ an energy eigenstate associated to the energy $E_n$. Then I want to compute $\langle \phi|\hat a^2|\phi \rangle$

- Option 1
  $$\langle \phi_n| (\hat{a} (\hat{a} | \phi_n \rangle)) \propto \langle \phi_n | \phi_{n-2} \rangle = 0 $$
- Option 2
  $$(\langle \phi_n|a)(a| \phi \rangle)$$

I mean, in the first case it gives zero, but what about the second case?

Comment: Can you define your system? Why do you say it is zero in the first case? For a generic state (not the ground state) you don't get zero

Comment: @ohneVal the action of a in this energy eigenstate will be; $$a|\phi> = \sqrt{\phi|}|\phi-1>$$, acting twice will give us $$ \sqrt{\phi(\phi-1)}|\phi-2>$$, this is orthogonal to $$<\phi|$$

Comment: Let us add all of that to the question to make it complete, by the way by the same logic both give 0.

Comment: You are currently still mixing up notation. When you write $|\phi\rangle$, do you always mean energy eigenstates $|\phi_n\rangle$ or are you interested in statements about general vectors $|\phi\rangle$? I assume from the way that the question is posed that all $|\phi\rangle$ should be replaced by $|\phi_n\rangle$ (and similarly for the bras)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second option also gives zero, operators can act to the left via adjoints,
that is
$$\hat{a}|\psi\rangle = (\langle \psi | \hat{a}^\dagger)^\dagger$$

or applied to your case
$$\langle \phi_n | \hat{a} = (\hat{a}^\dagger|\phi_n\rangle)^\dagger \propto \langle \phi_{n+1}|$$

Using the above result, you have
$$(\langle \phi_n |\hat{a})( \hat{a} |\phi_n\rangle) \propto \langle \phi_{n+1} | \phi_{n-1}\rangle = 0$$